# Inhomogeneous Initial value problem.

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

The solution to the initial value problem
$$x'(t)=Ax(t)+g(t)\quad\text{with}\quad x(0)=x_0$$
is
$$x(t)=\exp(tA)x_0+\int_0^t \exp((t-s)A)g(s)\,\mathrm{d}s$$

Suppose that all eigenvalues of $A$, satisfy $\mathrm{Re}(\alpha_j)<0$. I have to find
$$\lim_{t\to\infty} x(t)$$ when $$\lim_{t\to\infty} |g(t)|=g_0$$

I saw that the solution is $$x(t)=\exp(tA)x_0+\exp(tA)g_0$$
I get the same answer that it goes to zero just like in the case when $$\lim_{t\to\infty} |g(t)|=0$$
Is this right? If the first term goes to zero why doesn't the second as well?

This question is not answered in the dublicate.
Thank you for your help.

Klara

Answer (score 1):

You just check it with the explicit formula of the solution you give above.. The first part goes to 0 obviously, the second part needs one more comment that both exp(At) and g(t) is bounded.

Comment: could you please help me with my updated version?

Comment: @Klara, think about first order equation $\dot y=-y+1$. Do the solutions to this equation tend to zero?

Comment: @Artem no the solution of  the DE goes to 1, does that mean that my limit would go to g_0?

Comment: This means that the limit is not 0.

Comment: @ Artem Is it right that x(t)=\exp(tA)x_0+\exp(tA)g_0. If yes, then how is the second term any different from the first?

Comment: “I saw that the solution is 
x(t)=exp(tA)x 0 +exp(tA)g 0"
It's wrong..

Comment: @Lee do you know the answer? Can you explain it to me?

Comment: @Klara 'x(t)=exp(tA)x 0 +∫ t 0 exp((t−s)A)g(s)ds' This is correct. And without a given g(s) we cannot compute anything, yet you can analyze the tendancy when t goes to infinity.